# Exception using System.Net.Mqtt pre-release version

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mqtt, .net-4.6.1

I am trying to use Nuget package System.Net.Mqtt: a lightweight C#... 0.3.6-pre for my sample Mqtt app. However, I am not able to connect to my client. Code is below

```
namespace TestMqtt
{
    class MqttHelper
    {
        public IMqttClient client;

        public async Task CreateClient()
        {
            MqttConfiguration configuration = new MqttConfiguration();
            configuration.Port = 8883;
            configuration.AllowWildcardsInTopicFilters = false;
            configuration.KeepAliveSecs = 180;

            string address = Dns.GetHostAddresses("hostname")[0].ToString();
            client = await System.Net.Mqtt.MqttClient.CreateAsync(address, configuration);
        }

        public async Task Connect(MqttClientCredentials credentials)
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(credentials);
        }

        public bool IsConnected
        {
            get
            {
                return client.IsConnected;
            }
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                MqttHelper mqttHelper = new MqttHelper();

                Task.Run(() => mqttHelper.CreateClient()).Wait();

                MqttClientCredentials credentials = new MqttClientCredentials("clientId", "username", "password"); 

                Task.Run(() => mqttHelper.Connect(credentials)).Wait();

                bool connected = mqttHelper.IsConnected;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("exception occurred {0}, press key to exit", ex.InnerException);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I can connect with same credentials and host address by using another client M2Mqtt, so I am not sure what's wrong here. I am new to async stuff so there may something I am doing it wrong, but I tried all I can with no success. I get an exception - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in Connect method.

Any help will be appreciated, or if anyone has used the lib to connect please share the code. Nuget package documentation doesn't have any details on how to use the library. Any other suggestions for C# Mqtt client are welcome too, so far I have shortlisted M2Mqtt and Net.Mqtt for my use.

Thanks.